# QB Transaction not in balance message

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I am using Consolibyte QB PHP SDK (Qbxml). I am getting an error as

> Transaction not in balance

in couple of payment receive mod requests. Is this related with wrong qbxml or is it some issue/bug in QB Desktop (2021 version)?

error reported as

> 3170: There was an error when modifying a ReceivePayment.  QuickBooks error message: Transaction not in balance.

Comment: @Keith from Consolibyte, in case you have inputs then please share.

Comment: Post your code. Post the qbXML request. Highly unlikely it's a QuickBooks bug - you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem in Intuit QB SDK but on a PurchaseOrderAdd request. Sometimes I have item lines which have a 0 quantity and amount where a purchase order has had a complete item line reversed in my application. So I put in a quantity of 1 and an amount of 0.01 and it then went through.